# Minecraft beacon beam id/data

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering what a beacon's beam is or what it's made of. (e. g. Is it an entity etc.) and how I can have a beacon beam without a beacon.

Answer (score 2):

Beacon beams are specially rendered… things, which don't fall into any category like "entity" or "particle", just like crystal beams or the lines of fishing rods and leashes.

You cannot have a beacon beam without a beacon. Not even having a beacon tile entity without a beacon block works, it just gets deleted. The closest you can get to it is retexturing the beacon block to be invisible.

Comment: But lightning and leashknots can be summoned.

Comment: @Accorwolf Thanks, corrected!

Comment: Actually, sometimes particles are regular particles, but cannot be summoned, for example that recently happened in a snapshot. I'll ask some experts if these are maybe also particles like that.